# Vimfiler で .docファイルをWordで開く

Tags: macos, vim

環境：Mac (El Capitan)

Vimfilerで`.doc`ファイルをWordで開くために，この[リンク](https://github.com/Shougo/vimfiler.vim/issues/282)を参考に`.vmrc`に以下を設定しました。

`call vimfiler#set_execute_file('doc,docx', '/Applications/Microsoft Word.app')`

一方で，Vimfilerでファイルの選択後に`a`を押しても，actionリストに該当するような選択肢が見当たりません。（例えば，actionリストにある open を選択してお Word は起動しません。）

どうすれば`.doc`ファイルをWordで開くことができるかご教示お願いします。

Comment: アプリケーションのパスがWordではなく Excelになっていますが、これはただの書き間違いでしょうか？

Comment: Excelも試していたので，間違ってしまいました。Wordの間違いでした。Wordにしたとしても，同じ問題です。

Answer (score 2):

vimfiler の作者です。

`vimfiler#set_execute_list()` ですが、vimfiler のドキュメントを見れば分かるように、 `<Plug>(vimfiler_execute_vimfiler_associated)` マッピングを使わなければ効果が
ありません。専用のアクションはないので、a を押すと表れるアクション一覧には出てきません。
このマッピングは歴史的な事情により、どこにもマッピングされてないので、使用するにはどこかのキーに適当にマッピングしてください。

`<Plug>(vimfiler_execute_system_associated)` ですが、これは `vimfiler#set_execute_list()` ではなく、システムの関連付けを参照します。
仕組みは全然違う機能です。

今回の場合、doc ファイルがたまたま WORD に関連付けており、挙動が同じなので勘違いしてしまったのでしょう。

Answer (score -1):

解決しました。

Vimfilerでファイルの選択後に`a`を押すとactionリストが表示されますが，その中の`x`を選べばWordが起動しファイルが表示されます。

`x  <Plug>(vimfiler_execute_system_associated)`

Comment: I thought the answer may be useful for others. Voting down means that it should have been kept secret. Is that what you really want?